# How to prove that this is a parellelogram?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image: Trapezium]

> Prove that ABED is a parallelogram

**Given:**

1. ABCD is a trapezium
2. F and G are the midpoints of AB and DC respectively
3. FHG is a straight line
4. AD is equal to and parallel to BE

My attempts have included trying to show that $\angle BAD + \angle ADE = 180^{\circ}$ and trying to show that the opposite angles are equal. But these have not led me anywhere as at some point I am required to assume that AB and DE are parallel, which is what has to be proven. I'd like a hint; any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: 4. is the key.

Comment: @CatalinZara Do you mean to say that if AD is equal and parallel to BE , then there is no option but for the other to sides to be equal and parallel as well? No counterexample comes to mind for me.

Comment: What it implies is that same side interior angles add up to 180 degrees. Can you list two pairs of same side interior angles?

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber Yes. 4 gives all the answers you need.

Answer (score 1):

Steps  1,2,3 need not be given.

AD = BE and parallel to it, ABED is a parallelogram

So AB = DE and parallel to it, by parallelogram definition and property.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: draw $AE$ and show that triangles $ABE$ and $ADE$ are congruent.